# Nested attributes have root in rails 4 when y render JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I got a problem with my Rails app.
When I render a JSON, the nested attributes get repeated inside (like JSON example).
Here is my API Controller, Serializer, both models and JSON response.

PS: After a lot of updates I get started with this issue, before that, it work fine. I don't know what was. My ruby version is `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]` and my rails version is `Rails 4.2.4`

PS2: Sorry for my bad english

**ingreso.rb**

```
class Ingreso < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :departamento, touch: true
  belongs_to :concepto
[...]
end
```

**departamento.rb**

```
class Departamento < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ingresos
  [...]
end
```

**api/serializers/ingreso_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::IngresosController < Api::V1::BaseController
  include ActiveHashRelation

  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  def show_for_departamento
    ingresos = Ingreso.where(departamento_id:params[:id]).order("id DESC")
    render(
      json: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(
        ingresos,
        each_serializer: Api::V1::IngresoSerializer,
        root: 'ingresos'
        )
      )
  end
```

**api/serializers/ingreso_serializer.rb**

```
class Api::V1::IngresoSerializer < Api::V1::BaseSerializer
  attributes :field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :concepto, :colaborador, :departamento

  def formapago
    object.try(:formapago).try(:nombre) || "Sin información"
  end

  def colaborador
    object.try(:colaborador).try(:full_name) || "Sin información"
  end
  def created_at
    object.created_at.in_time_zone.iso8601 if object.created_at
  end

  def updated_at
    object.updated_at.in_time_zone.iso8601 if object.created_at
  end
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "myRoot": [
    {
      "field1": 13201,
      "field2": -5720,
      "field3": null,
      "field4": "2016-04-11T00:00:00.000-04:00",
      "field5": "2016-04-10T00:00:00.000-04:00",

      "concepto": {
        "concepto": {
          "data1": 1,
          "data2": "Gasto Común",
          "created_at": "2013-01-03T15:49:16.000-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2015-02-05T15:54:12.363-04:00",
          "data3": 1,
          "data4": "gasto-comun",
          "data5": false
        }
      },
      "colaborador": "Sin información",
      "departamento": {
        "departamento": {
          "another_field1": 101,
          "another_field2": "1305",
          "another_field3": 370,
          "another_field4": 1,
          "created_at": "2013-01-05T01:05:36.000-04:00",
          "updated_at": "2016-05-20T11:48:30.892-04:00",
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a solution. In my `ingreso_serializer.rb` I define `departamento` like this:

```
class Api::V1::IngresoSerializer < Api::V1::BaseSerializer
  attributes :field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :concepto, :colaborador, :departamento
  def departamento
    object.departamento.as_json(root: false, include: :propietario)
  end

  def concepto
    object.concepto.as_json(root: false)
  end

end
```